# Integration of $\int\frac{x^{4}}{x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you help me with the following integral:

$$\int\frac{x^{4}}{x+1}dx$$

Comment: If you do not think of the clever trick of the current answers, let $u=x+1$. Then we are integrating $\frac{(u-1)^4}{u}$. Expand the top, divide by $u$ term by term.

Comment: Or, just do the division.

Comment: Hint: Add and subtract -1 from numerator and factorize first part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: $$x^4=x^4-1+1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)+1$$

**Generalization** : For integer $n\ge1,$

$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1)$$

For $x=y^2,y^{2n}-1=(y^2-1)(y^{2(n-1)}+y^{2(n-2)}+\cdots+y^2+1)$

$\iff y^{2n}-1=(y-1)(y+1)(y^{2n-2}+y^{2n-4}+\cdots+y^2+1)$

Comment: Ah, easy now! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\int\frac{x^4}{x+1}dx=\int\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}dx+\int \frac{dx}{x+1}\\=\int(x-1)(x^2+1)dx+\ln(1+x)+c$$

Comment: Why is the downvote?